# Too many redirects error using cloudflare

Tags: wordpress, ssl, redirect, dns, cloudflare

I redirected two URLs from one of my sites to another. Those two site redirects are working fine however all the other pages including the home URL are giving a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error . It was working until the DNS propagation completed.
[Too many redirect error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w9FE.png)

I have tried disabling all the plugins including the SSL and the existing redirection plugin (which was not used in the processes). I checked the cloudflare DNS records and everything seem fine on that side. What could be causing this problem? Is there anything in particular I should be looking for?
The redirection of the 2 URLs is working however I expected the homepage to open as usual. Instead I'm getting a redirection loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To further troubleshoot, ensure that your origin server's configuration is correct and not causing additional redirects. Verify that your Cloudflare settings, especially the Page Rules, aren't causing conflicts. Double-check your WordPress site's settings for any hardcoded URLs that might be triggering redirects. Also, make sure your SSL settings in both Cloudflare and your origin server are properly configured.

If the issue persists, I'd say reaching out to Cloudflare's support.